# post loop with different design depending on post

Tags: posts, wp-query, archive-template

I'm having a lot of trouble finding the solution.
I would like to loop my last 3 posts with wp-query.
I would like the 1st post to be in one div and the last 2 posts in another different div.
So when I publish a new post the last post goes to div 1 and the previous one goes down to the 2nd div etc...

**here is an example**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_per_page' => 3,
);

<?php $loop = new WP_Query($args);

$count = 0;
 while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
if ($count == 0):
?>

    <!-- last post -->
    <div class="post-one">
        <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
    </div>
<?php else:?>

    <!-- second et third post -->
    <div class="post-two">
    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt();?>
    </div>

<?php
$count ++;
endif;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$count++` needs to be after your `endif` statement.  It's not counting up because your counter is always at 0 which means you're always in your "if" portion of your statement not your "else".
Like this:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_per_page' => 3,
    );

<?php $loop = new WP_Query($args);

$count = 0;
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    if ($count == 0):
    ?>
        <!-- last post -->
        <div class="post-one">
            <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
        </div>
    <?php else:?>
    
        <!-- second et third post -->
        <div class="post-two">
        <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt();?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endif;
    $count ++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: It's okay thank you. I found a small error in my code `'post_per_page' => 3,` to `'posts_per_page' => 3,`

Answer (score 0):

You have error in code

```
if ($count == ):
```

it should be

```
if ($count == 0):
```

Comment: Yes I know but that doesn't solve my problem :s